# Calculating the % of Zero-Return days using R

Tags: r

I need some help in calculating a liquidity measure for my thesis. I need to use "the % of Zero-Return days". This measure for each firm and for each year calculates the proportion of days with zero stock returns to number of trading days in each year. For example, I have the following dataset:

```
Date      Firm    Return
1/1/2009   A       2    
2/1/2009   A       0   
3/1/2009   A       0
4/1/2009   A       2
1/1/2010   A       1.5
2/1/2010   A       0
3/1/2010   A       6
4/1/2010   A       7
1/1/2009   B       0   
2/1/2009   B       0
3/1/2009   B       0
1/1/2010   B       11
2/1/2010   B       0
3/1/2010   B       0
4/1/2010   B       0
5/1/2010   B       10
```

the result should be like the following:

```
Date      Firm     %Zero   
2009       A        0.5
2010       A        0.25
2009       B         1
2010       B        0.6
```

I can do this calculation by hand but it will take a long time since I have more that 1000 firms and a study period of 10 years. Some people suggest that I should use loops or a package called `dplyr`. However, my experience with R is very basic. I hope someone can help me with this issue. I would be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use base R's `aggregate()`, taking the mean of the number of `Return` values that are equal to zero.  Also, `transform()` is used to temporarily change the `Date` column to just the year.  Original data remains unchanged.

```
aggregate(
    cbind(PctZero = Return == 0) ~ ., 
    transform(df, Date = sub(".*/", "", Date)), 
    mean
)
#   Date Firm PctZero
# 1 2009    A    0.50
# 2 2010    A    0.25
# 3 2009    B    1.00
# 4 2010    B    0.60
```

Note that beginning a column name with a special character (`%Zero`) is not advised, so I went with `PctZero`.

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
8L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("1/1/2009", "1/1/2010", 
"2/1/2009", "2/1/2010", "3/1/2009", "3/1/2010", "4/1/2009", "4/1/2010", 
"5/1/2010"), class = "factor"), Firm = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), Return = c(2, 0, 0, 2, 1.5, 0, 6, 7, 
0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 10)), .Names = c("Date", "Firm", "Return"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Rich Scriven. Your code worked perfectly even with `NA` values. I really appreciate your help and thank for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using data.table which is very fast and efficient, and with a clean syntax for these cases:

```
library(data.table)

returns <- fread("your_csv_file.csv", header=T)
returns$Date <- year(as.Date(returns$Date, "%d/%m/%Y"))
returns[, list('%Zero'=sum(Return==0)/length(Return)), by=list(Firm, Date)]
```

Comment: `sum(Return==0)/length(Return)` is equivalent to `mean(Return == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,.(year(as.Date(Date,format="%m/%d/%Y)),Firm),summarize,length(Return==0)/length(Date))
```

Comment: thank you @Alexey Ferapontov for your help. But for the record, I need to install package `plyr` before I can use function `ddply`

Comment: Yes, I should have added the library in the answer.